# v-on:keup event triggers Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined at setFieldValue at HTMLFormElement.formKeydownListener

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

The following form is triggered on Enter key press:

```
<form data-type="json" action="/api/v4/items/:id" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
  <input v-model = "name" name="name" v-on:keyup.enter = "renameItem();">
</form>
```

`renameItem()` method it's here:

```
renameItem: function() {
  $(this).closest('form').submit();
}
```

This works fine, but after the form is submitted i get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at setFieldValue (onloadwff.js:71)
    at HTMLFormElement.formKeydownListener (onloadwff.js:71)
```

Comment: Do you use the LastPass browser plugin?

Comment: By chance are you using LastPass? https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/236#issuecomment-262287678

Comment: thanks @JKL and aprouja1. The issue was with LastPass